# String error in jquery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I am writing a generic code to disable select box option and calling it from many places. This gives me Unexpected token ILLEGAL . I tried multiple ways but did not get my result.

```
var SelectBox ={
    disableOptionInSelection : function(selectID,valueToDisable){
        $("#"+selectID+" option[value*='+valueToDisable+']").prop('disabled',true);
    }
};
SelectBox.disableOptionInSelection("#myid","Hello");
```

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable passed ,but the syntax is not right
Should be like this:

```
 var SelectBox={
              disableOptionInSelection : function(selectID,valueToDisable){
                 $("#"+selectID+" option[value*='"+valueToDisable+"']").prop('disabled',true);

              }
            };
SelectBox.disableOptionInSelection("#myid","Hello");
```

Comment: @s_k_t Notice the quotes around `+valueToDisable+`.